# Http Requests Bitcoin Mining Pool?

Tags: api, php, webminer

Is there any pool where I can complete mining work for a mining pool via and http requests? Some sort of API?

I have access to a lot of computational power that I want to route to a mining pool using php..

Something like this:

1) visit url (including login details)

2) response includes mining work/problem

3) visit different url to submit completed work and have tiny payout from pool

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key aspects of a mining protocol is that the miners should be informed immediately when a new block is confirmed on the network. Otherwise, they will continue working on the old block which would then be useless work.

This is why there is not a simple GET/POST protocol for mining. The miners keep a connection open to the pool servers, so that there can be immediate two-way communication between them (from the miner for the case of a share completed, or from the server in the case of a new block).

Comment: what protocol is used? how could it be connected with a web address? :)

Comment: The common protocols are [getwork](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getwork) (not used much today), [getblocktemplate](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Getblocktemplate), and [stratum](https://mining.bitcoin.cz/stratum-mining).

Comment: I think we could leverage notification work to push notification, so, aside from that are there any more thing cannot implement as restful ?